# Create global temporary table in oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, transactions, locking

I have situation where i am running many procedures parallel which are accessing the same table. When i try to run those procedures parallely i can see few of the procedures throws an error `ORA-00054: resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified or timeout expired`. Those tables are temporary tables where i am deleting the old data first and then inserting. And again doing the same thing for next procedure run. So in this case i have situation where multiple procedures try to access the same table and try to perform DML operations. I have solution of  creation global temporary table for this case:

```
CRATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE TEMP_ACTIVATE_OPTION(
  ID   NUMBER,
  ... -- your columns
)
ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS;
```

But as i am new to this solution i really dont know how it works. For example if a procedure is running and trying to access the table `TEMP_ACTIVATE_OPTION` for DML operations and another procedure runs parallely and trying to access the same table `TEMP_ACTIVATE_OPTION` for DML operations then in this is there a possibitly of data loss or conflict ? How do global temporary tables manage the sessions ot transaction ? Do it perform a lock on table if procedure try to do dml operations on that table and it waits to release the lock on table so that another procedure can access the same table?

```
PROCEDURE                    "EXT_10024_ACTIVATE_OPTION"(IN_KPI_DEF_ID IN NUMBER DEFAULT 0) AS

IN_EVENT_ID NUMBER;
err_code VARCHAR(100);
err_msg VARCHAR(100);
IN_OBJECT_NAME VARCHAR2(100);

CURSOR KPI_DEF_CUR IS
Select KPI_DEF_ID,BUSINESS_CHECK_PERIOD_ID,BUS_CHK_PRD_ID_1,
CASE WHEN BUSINESS_CHECK_PERIOD_UNIT_ID=11 THEN 'MINUTE'
WHEN BUSINESS_CHECK_PERIOD_UNIT_ID=12 THEN 'HOUR'
WHEN BUSINESS_CHECK_PERIOD_UNIT_ID=13 THEN 'DAY'
WHEN BUSINESS_CHECK_PERIOD_UNIT_ID IS NULL THEN 'MINUTE'
END AS BUSINESS_CHECK_PERIOD_UNIT_ID,
CASE WHEN BUSINESS_CHK_PERIOD_VAL IS NULL THEN 0
ELSE BUSINESS_CHK_PERIOD_VAL END AS BUSINESS_CHK_PERIOD_VAL,
CASE WHEN BUS_CHK_PRD_UNIT_ID_1=11 THEN 'MINUTE'
WHEN BUS_CHK_PRD_UNIT_ID_1=12 THEN 'HOUR'
WHEN BUS_CHK_PRD_UNIT_ID_1=13 THEN 'DAY'
WHEN BUS_CHK_PRD_UNIT_ID_1 IS NULL THEN 'MINUTE'
END AS BUS_CHK_PRD_UNIT_ID_1,
CASE WHEN BUS_CHK_PRD_VAL_1 IS NULL THEN 0
ELSE BUS_CHK_PRD_VAL_1 END AS BUS_CHK_PRD_VAL_1,
EVENT_ID FROM RATOR_MONITORING_CONFIGURATION.KPI_DEFINITION where KPI_DEF_ID = IN_KPI_DEF_ID;

BEGIN

--delete the data from TEMP_SERVICE_OPTION and TEMP_SERVICE_OPTION_EXTRACTION
Delete from TEMP_ACTIVATE_OPTION;
Delete from TEMP_SERVICE_OPTION_EXTRACTION;
Delete from TEMP_SERVICE_OPTION;

DELETE FROM CAPTURED_DATA_ERROR WHERE EVENT_TIMESTAMP < SYSDATE - 60 and EVENT_ID=10024;

-- removed, retrieve  a new START_ID from source first, don't use the last id.
-- SELECT LAST_TASK_ID INTO LAST_SO_ID FROM CAPTURING where DB_TABLE='TEMP_SERVICE_OPTION';
--SELECT MIN(SO.ID) INTO LAST_SO_ID FROM SERVICE_OPTION@FONIC_RETAIL SO WHERE SO.ID >= to_char(SYSDATE -1, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')||'0000';

Select EVENT_ID INTO IN_EVENT_ID FROM RATOR_MONITORING_CONFIGURATION.KPI_DEFINITION where KPI_DEF_ID = IN_KPI_DEF_ID;

FOR KPI_DEF_ROW IN KPI_DEF_CUR
LOOP

BEGIN
INSERT INTO TEMP_ACTIVATE_OPTION(ID,ICC,ASSIGNED_ANUMBER_ID,SERVICE_ID,PRODUCT_OPTION_ID,STATUS_ID,END_DATE,PRODUCT_TYPE_KEY)
Select DISTINCT(SO.ID),SIM.ICC,SIM.ASSIGNED_ANUMBER_ID,SO.SERVICE_ID,SO.PRODUCT_OPTION_ID,SO.STATUS_ID,SO.END_DATE,SIM.PRODUCT_TYPE_KEY FROM
SIMCARD@FONIC_RETAIL SIM
  JOIN SERVICE_OPTION@FONIC_RETAIL SO ON SO.SERVICE_ID=SIM.ASSIGNED_TO_SERVICE_ID
 where SO.STATUS_ID IN (20,40)
and SO.ID < to_char(SYSDATE - numtodsinterval (  KPI_DEF_ROW.BUSINESS_CHK_PERIOD_VAL,KPI_DEF_ROW.BUSINESS_CHECK_PERIOD_UNIT_ID ), 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')||'0000'
 and SO.ID > to_char(SYSDATE - numtodsinterval ( KPI_DEF_ROW.BUS_CHK_PRD_VAL_1, KPI_DEF_ROW.BUS_CHK_PRD_UNIT_ID_1 ), 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')||'0000'
and NOT EXISTS(SELECT ID from TEMP_ACTIVATE_OPTION T WHERE T.ID = SO.ID );

EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NO_DATA_FOUND exception in EXT_10024_ACTIVATE_OPTION - KPI_DEF_ID:'||to_char(IN_KPI_DEF_ID));
RAISE;

END;

commit;

BEGIN
INSERT INTO TEMP_SERVICE_OPTION_EXTRACTION(ID,ICC,ASSIGNED_ANUMBER_ID,SERVICE_ID,PRODUCT_OPTION_ID,STATUS_ID,END_DATE,A_NUMBER,PRODUCT_TYPE_KEY)
Select DISTINCT(SO.ID),SO.ICC,SO.ASSIGNED_ANUMBER_ID,SO.SERVICE_ID,SO.PRODUCT_OPTION_ID,SO.STATUS_ID,SO.END_DATE,AN.A_NUMBER,SO.PRODUCT_TYPE_KEY FROM
TEMP_ACTIVATE_OPTION SO JOIN
PRODUCT_OPTION@FONIC_RETAIL PO ON SO.PRODUCT_OPTION_ID = PO.ID JOIN
PRODUCT_CONFIG@FONIC_RETAIL PC ON PO.OPTION_KEY=PC.DEFAULT_PRODUCT_OPTIONS
JOIN PRODUCT_TYPE@FONIC_RETAIL PT ON PC.ID = PT.PRODUCT_CONFIG_ID
JOIN TEMP_ACTIVATE_OPTION SO ON SO.PRODUCT_TYPE_KEY=PT.KEY
JOIN
A_NUMBER@FONIC_RETAIL AN ON SO.ASSIGNED_ANUMBER_ID = AN.ID
where SO.STATUS_ID IN (20,40)
and NOT EXISTS(SELECT ID from TEMP_SERVICE_OPTION_EXTRACTION T WHERE T.ID = SO.ID );

EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NO_DATA_FOUND exception in EXT_10024_ACTIVATE_OPTION - KPI_DEF_ID:'||to_char(IN_KPI_DEF_ID));
RAISE;

END;

commit;

BEGIN
--SELF_REGISTRATION ACTIVATE OPTION
INSERT INTO TEMP_SERVICE_OPTION(ID,SERVICE_ID,PRODUCT_OPTION_ID,STATUS_ID,EVENT_TIMESTAMP,END_DATE,EVENT_ID,SUBSCRIPTION_ID,ORDER_NUMBER,A_NUMBER)
Select DISTINCT(SO.ID),SO.SERVICE_ID,SO.PRODUCT_OPTION_ID,SO.STATUS_ID,to_date(substr(SO.ID, 1, 14), 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS'),SO.END_DATE,
IN_EVENT_ID
,TSM.SUBSCRIPTION_ID,TSM.ORDER_NUMBER,SO.A_NUMBER
from TEMP_SERVICE_OPTION_EXTRACTION SO JOIN TMP_SOAP_MONITORING_IDS TSM
ON SO.A_NUMBER = TSM.MSISDN
where SO.STATUS_ID IN (20,40) and TSM.ORDER_TYPE='SELF_REGISTRATION' and
TSM.CREATE_DATE < SYSDATE - numtodsinterval (  KPI_DEF_ROW.BUSINESS_CHK_PERIOD_VAL,KPI_DEF_ROW.BUSINESS_CHECK_PERIOD_UNIT_ID )
and TSM.CREATE_DATE > SYSDATE - numtodsinterval ( KPI_DEF_ROW.BUS_CHK_PRD_VAL_1, KPI_DEF_ROW.BUS_CHK_PRD_UNIT_ID_1 )
and NOT EXISTS(SELECT ID from TEMP_SERVICE_OPTION T WHERE T.ID = SO.ID )
and TSM.WEB_SERVICE_NAME ='RatorWebShopService' and TSM.WEB_METHOD_NAME ='placeShopOrder';

EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('NO_DATA_FOUND exception in EXT_10024_ACTIVATE_OPTION - KPI_DEF_ID:'||to_char(IN_KPI_DEF_ID));
RAISE;

END;

END LOOP;

commit;

--INSERT TEMP DATA INTO CAPTURED_DATA_01 TABLE
Insert into CAPTURED_DATA_01(SUBSCRIPTION_ID,ENV_ID,BRAND_ID,BP_ID,EVENT_ID,ORDER_ID,STATUS_DESCRIPTION,STATUS_CODE,EVENT_TIMESTAMP)
Select DISTINCT(DCR.SUBSCRIPTION_ID),BBE.ENV_ID,TSM.BRAND_ID,BBE.BP_ID,DCR.EVENT_ID,
DCR.ORDER_NUMBER,
CASE WHEN DCR.STATUS_ID=20 THEN 'OK'
WHEN DCR.STATUS_ID=40 THEN 'ERROR'
END,DCR.STATUS_ID,
DCR.EVENT_TIMESTAMP from TEMP_SERVICE_OPTION DCR JOIN TMP_SOAP_MONITORING_IDS TSM ON TSM.SUBSCRIPTION_ID=DCR.SUBSCRIPTION_ID
JOIN
RATOR_MONITORING_CONFIGURATION.ENV_BRAND_BP_EVENT BBE ON BBE.EVENT_ID = DCR.EVENT_ID JOIN
RATOR_MONITORING_CONFIGURATION.ENVIRONMENT ENV on BBE.ENV_ID=ENV.ENV_ID
JOIN RATOR_MONITORING_CONFIGURATION.BRAND BR ON BBE.BRAND_ID = BR.BRAND_ID
JOIN RATOR_MONITORING_CONFIGURATION.BUSINESS_PROCESS BP ON BBE.BP_ID = BP.BP_ID
AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT CD.SUBSCRIPTION_ID FROM CAPTURED_DATA_01 CD WHERE CD.EVENT_ID = DCR.EVENT_ID AND CD.SUBSCRIPTION_ID = DCR.SUBSCRIPTION_ID);

EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
err_code := SQLCODE;
err_msg := SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1, 200);

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('OTHERS exception in EXT_10072_REQ_SENT_SPAIN - KPI_DEF_ID:'||to_char(IN_KPI_DEF_ID) || err_code || '----' || err_msg || 'OBJECT_NAME->');
RAISE;

COMMIT;


END EXT_10024_ACTIVATE_OPTION;
```

Comment: Is `CAPTURED_DATA_ERROR` a temporary table? If no, then I would expect the delete on that table to be the cause of the ORA-00054, not the temporary tables (as they would not cause that error). Also: `distinct` is ***NOT*** a function. It always applies to **all** columns in the `select` statement. `distinct(so.id)` makes no sense.

Comment: How can be delete on CAPTURED_DATA_ERROR creates problem ? Its not a temporary table but it has very few data.

Comment: This can happen when a second transaction tries to delete the *same* rows as another transaction (although I would have expected the second one to wait).

Comment: no the second transaction is not trying to delete the same row because i am providing different event_id for each deletion of captured_data_error :

Comment: You need to trap the **exact** operation where that error occurs. Otherwise all this is just guessing.

Comment: i have put exception wherever it is required and i mentioned the error i am getting in my procedures. Its related to some transaction handling.

Comment: No, you are not catching the ORA-00054. So you do not know the operation that is the root cause of the error.

Comment: i dont understand what you want to suggest. Can you please elaborate more ?

Comment: Is there any reason to get negative vote for my question ? What was mistake ? I will correct it.

Comment: Negative votes are usually because the question is not well worded, specified, or researched, not necessarily because you made a mistake. If you improve your question (e.g. reduce the wall of code to a simple reproducible test case) so that it may become more useful to other people in the future, you may get rewarded with upvotes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here's the official manual on temporary tables](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tables003.htm#ADMIN11633).

> The definition of a temporary table is visible to all sessions, but
>   the data in a temporary table is visible only to the session that
>   inserts the data into the table.

In short, you can *think* of global temporary table as if a *private instance* of that table is created for your session when you first access the table. What actually happens inside is another story, but you should leave that to Oracle - what you see at your level of abstraction is a table completely private to your session.

No other session can access the data your session has in GTT, and the data is always lost as soon as you close your session. No other session can "lock" rows in your session, since they aren't visible, and no conflicts can happen.

You also should differentiate transaction- and session-specific GTT. they are created using `ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS` and `ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS` respectively, and do exactly what these instructions say: transaction-specific GTT clears your table on every `COMMIT` you issue, and session-specific keeps the data until your session ends or you delete it manually.

One downside you should be aware of is that to issue DDL statements except truncate (alter table, for example), you'll have to kill all sessions that are using the instances of said GTT first. Plan your maintenance accordingly.

Comment: I am not issuing any ddl statement, you can see in my code its only the DML operation i am performing. But stll i have confusion that if multiple procedure try to access the same table at the same time and perform DML operation like delete and then insert so in this case doi face issue of data loss ? If one procedure took 50sec to run and complete dml operation on the table and another procedure try to access the same table for dml operation then in this case how does GTT handle such transaction/session ?

Comment: When working with GTT, you don't care what other sessions are doing with it, because you have your own instance. Other sessions can't access your data, they can't read it, they can't delete it, it's all yours. How would you expect data loss to happen, exactly? I don't understand what you're referring to with "such" transaction.

Comment: I mean to say for example my procedure is performaing DML operation on table so it has a sesssion and another procedure try to perform the dml operation on the same table at the same time then it also has their own session. So if this 2 sessions are ruuning at the same time then what will happen ?

Comment: So if one session trying to delete the data from table and another session try to insert the data on the same table then the conflict could occur right?

Comment: Nothing. Both will work with their own data, no conflicts or anything. That's what GTT are made for. Just like with regular tables, you can have a dozen sessions doing DML all at the same time, but since all the data is private no row-level conflicts can happen by definition. Also, procedure can't "have" a session - you start a session by connecting to your DB (with username/password) and execute procedure(s) and/or any other statements *in* the session you have started.

Comment: ok i understood now. I will try to create GTT now instead of normal temporary tables and execute procedure again to check the same error exists or not. Thanks :)

Comment: I have just a small question and query @Timekiller . Using GTT ON COMMIT clause indicates if the data in the table is transaction-specific (the default) or session-specific and it truncates after each commit. So as per in my  code if i create GTT for TEMP_ACTIVATE_OPTION,TEMP_SERVICE_OPTION_EXTRACTION,TEMP_SERVICE_OPTION then before insert into CAPTURED_DATA_01 table which is not temporary table the the above tables will get deleted right ? It it is then it will not help me because i am insert data into CAPTURED_DATA_01 table from TEMP_SERVICE_OPTION table.

Comment: Data is truncated on commit only in transaction-specific GTT, I pointed that out in my answer. You either create transaction-specific tables and don't commit before inserting to `CAPTURED_DATA_01` or create session-specific tables and clear them manually - you already do that at the beginning of procedure, I think. I don't see the problem.

Comment: i have tested both the GTT on commit clause and it works successfully. I just got a small question in this if i create GTT using ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS which is session specific then how do the session got killed? Because i have lots of parallel procedures running at the same time accessing the same table and there will be many sessions gets created for this and during the next procedure run it should create new sessions and the previous sessions should get killed right?

Comment: Are you mixing up session and transaction? Session is created only once when you connect to database, it's killed when you disconnect. Transaction is everything you do between commits.

Comment: I have application which is connected to database and running on production database so there is very less possibility that it should get disconnect. So if i create session specific GTT then the session which are created for temp table will remain active and runs during each and every procedure call right ? And in transaction specific GTT it only happens during commit. So i think in my case its better to create transaction specific GTT and i will commit after inserting to CAPTURED_DATA_01 table.

Comment: So if any other transaction running parallel and using the same table for DML will not get affect right?

Comment: Again: **session is only created when you login**. It isn't "created for temp table". You can't run procedures in parallel within a single session. Your application either uses a connection pool, i.e. keeps multiple sessions open and reuses them, or connects anew for each procedure call. Also, I'm getting tired of explaining the basics over and over, please read Oracle's official manuals, or experiment by yourself.